# Modulo: The Purpose of An Undefined Integer

Tags: c++, c++11, modulus

I am having some trouble understanding what a few lines mean in a code. I recently started learning C++ and picked up Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++." There is a question in chapter 4 that was tripping me up, so I searched for a solution online to reference. Here is the code I ended up using in conjunction with the book:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

bool prime(vector<int> store, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < store.size(); ++i)
    if (number%store[i] == 0) return false; //line that I don't understand
    return true;
}

int main() {

    int max;
    cout << "Please enter a maximum number you want checked for being prime or not.\n";
    cin >> max;
    vector<int> store;
    for (int n = 2; n <= max; ++n)
        if (prime(store, n)) store.push_back(n);
    for (int n = 0; n < store.size(); ++n)
        cout << store[n] << "\n";

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

The objective of the code is to find all prime numbers below and equal to the user input, starting at 2. I understand everything that is going on in this code with the exception of one line (notated by the comment). **What is the purpose of the int "number" on this line, and what mathematically is going on here?** The aspect of it that is confusing me is "number" doesn't have a value, yet it is being divided by the value of the current element. If it equals zero, then theoretically the statement is false. Can someone please explain this to me? What does it have to do with finding prime numbers? I want to know what is happening at a basic level so that I may become a more efficient programmer and make my own solution. Thanks.

Comment: % is used for calculating remainder

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I meant in reference to the undefined integer "number" if that makes sense.

Comment: the value n in "if (prime(store, n))" will be passed to number in "bool prime(vector<int> store, int number)". Basically you are passing value to a function

Comment: Why do you think `number` is "undefined" or "doesn't have a value" ?

Comment: if (number%store[i] == 0) return false; //line that I don't understand
This keeps on checking with previous qualified prime ..if the new contender is not divided by them

Comment: number *does* have a value...

Comment: `number` is not an undefined integer, it is the parameter passed into the function. so when you call `prime(store, 42))`, `number` would be `42`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of `prime`, `store` has prime numbers less than `number` so far.

`number` is a prime if and only if it's not divisible by any integers (beside 0 and 1) smaller than it

Comment: That clears up quite a bit. Essentially, it is dividing the undefined value (which becomes the current one in the loop), by all previous integers in the loop. If in any case there is no remainder, it becomes a false statement. Otherwise, it is true and therefore is prime. Right? Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int n = 2; n <= max; ++n)
    if (prime(store, n)) store.push_back(n);
```

Here the function is called repeatedly and the value of n is 2 at the beginning as
the for loop is iterating n starting from 2. This value of n is the value of number in the function body.

Hope that clears.

Comment: That helped clear it up even further. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

> The aspect of it that is confusing me is "number" doesn't have a value

`number` does have a value: whatever value was passed in the call to `prime()`.  In `main()`, `prime()` is called first with number=2, then number=3, ... up to number=max.

Other answers have addressed the mathematical [reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) behind the program.

If you want to understand how this program works - and inspecting the value of `number` during a call to `prime()`, as well as the call stack, is a great way to do that - I would suggest learning how to use a debugger such as gdb and poking around.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thank you for the tip. I'll be sure to look into it.